# LiveChatMessages insert does not show up in chat with a status of 200

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a chat bot that listens to commands like !Commands, !Sounds, !Podcast, and other ![Command} messages and sends a response.

The code does just that.  Sets the body, sends a post to the correct location. :)  The response I get is a 200 with a chat message response.  Telling me what message was inserted into the chat.

Why would I get a 200 and the message not show up in the chat?

Now, it might be that I ran into my quota limit.  During streaming I couldn't get a list of messages because I hit my quota limit.  Is it possible LiveChatMessage.Insert returns 200 even at my quota limit?

Thanks. :)